# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All requested items must be referenced by specific ID (Android)

Tags: android, storage, mediastore, android-10.0, android-11

I'm getting this exception upon calling `MediaStore.createWriteRequest(contentResolver, uris)`. As in Anrdroid Q and above we have to make createWriteRequest to write on storage. So I'm trying the following code and getting the exception.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            List<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
            uris.add(mediaUri);
            MediaStore.createWriteRequest(contentResolver, uris);
            //code
        }
```

Comment: So what is `mediaUri`? Does it reference a specific `MediaStore` item by ID?

Comment: I'm initializing mediaUri as `mediaUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);`

Comment: You are not specifying what should be written. mediaUri denotes the "area". Use appendedId for example final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

Comment: Your trick is good but I was still getting the same exception with this but by using your code, I modified it like `final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId( MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY), Long.valueOf(id));` and the error is gone. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**Your Uri path is wrong that's the reason the error message is shown.**

**Invalid Uri Path:** content://com.abc.photoapp.provider/external_files/emulated/0/Pictures/camara/1623819097267.jpg

**Valid Path is :**
content://media/external/images/media/52703

**Here, I explain the file path to delete media step by step.**

**Step 1:**

Suppose You have a file path like this
"/storage/emulated/0/tempPic/export_image.jpg"

```
File tempFile=new File("/storage/emulated/0/tempPic/export_image.jpg");
long mediaID=getFilePathToMediaID(tempFile.getAbsolutePath(),  context);

public long getFilePathToMediaID(String songPath, Context context)
{
        long id = 0;
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
        String[] selectionArgs = {songPath};
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID};
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, selection + "=?", selectionArgs, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                id = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(idIndex));
            }
        }

        return id;
}
```

**Step 2:**

Create media id to Uri

```
Uri Uri_one = ContentUris.withAppendedId( MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri("external"),mediaID);

// content://media/external/images/media/52703
```

The content Uri change according to your file type:

If Image then : MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri("external")
If Video then : MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri("external")

**Step 3:**

Prepare and call to delete

```
List<Uri> uris=new ArrayList<>();
uris.add(<Add Paht : Uri_one >);
uris.add(<Add Paht : Uri_two >);
uris.add(<Add Paht : Uri_three >);

requestDeletePermission( context,uris);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHeRU.jpg)
After you call the method ask permission dialog. requestDeletePermission method is return result on onActivityResult method.

The above method support android 11 (Target SDK Version 30 ) and a greater version. You do not require manage_external_storage permission for media file delete. You can use media like Video, Audio, and Images.

If you want to delete a document file so you must require manage_external_storage permission.