# file.delete() Always returns false in Android java(Android 11+ deives)?

Tags: java, android, delete-file

I'm trying to delete a file in android storage. But the file is not getting deleted.
I trapped on this issue almost 3 days. I tired all the solution as of my knowledge, but nothing hellps. Your help will be highly useful to me thanks in advance.

I used the below code to delete

```
 String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Recordings/Call/Two.mp3";
        File fdelete = new File(path);
        if (fdelete.exists()) {
          boolean  b = fdelete.delete();
          if (b) {
             System.out.println("file Deleted :" + path);
          } else {
             System.out.println("file not Deleted :" + path);
     }
}
```

And the permission I used in manifest are

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Use file.canWrite() too before you try to delete.

Comment: How did that file land on your device?

Comment: Android version of used device?

Comment: Im trying on android 11 and 11+ devices

Comment: 10 and below 10 working fine bro

Comment: I manually downloaded the file

Comment: @ஆனந்த் have you found any solution. solution kedachudha bro..

Comment: @sanojlawrence We cannot delete files automatically on android 11+ devices bro

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68080701/5197712 Check this answer bro @sanojlawrence