# Android 11 scoped storage permissions issue & how to use them properly?

Tags: android, google-play-console, mediastore, android-11, scoped-storage

I have a **Cleaner app** in java that has features like - System cleaner, Whatsapp manager, and **Basic file Explorer** to list & delete files **i.e. downloads, images, videos, documents and audio.**

Now it has to comply with Google's scoped storage enforcement or it will be removed from the store.

My question here is:

> - How to I make sure I am using **correct permissions** to comply with this policy? While making sure the older versions of Android would
>   still work as normally (or scoped storage api works with them too?).

What I have already done:

```
<uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
            android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

> - I have updated the permissions as shown above^ and set target sdk to 30, as well as removed `requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag from
>   manifest file.
> - Notice that WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is using max sdk = 28 tag, do I need to do this with other two (READ&WRITE) permissions also? (official doc only showed example of write-external-storage permission)
> - I'm still asking for these permissions in java code - do I need to wrap that code using `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 30)` to make sure
>   it's only asked in lower android versions or using the above tag in
>   manifest already takes care of that for me?
> - I have already implemented the `requestDeletePermission()` dialog for deleting files in Android 11 - it works! But for listing files in Basic explorer I'm
>   still using the old code that worked in old Android versions - do I
>   need to update that too? (Although it's still working with above 3 permissions)

Please help me I really have to finish it before the end of this month or my app will get removed. The whole point is to avoid violating the new policy in Android 11. **I'm willing to give higher bounty to elaborative answers.**

Thank you.

Comment: `android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` What is that? Better remove. Request the other to always. Keep the requestLegacyExternalStorage otherwise your app will not run on Android 10 devices. You should always ask for runtime permissions.

Comment: keeping the requestLegacyExternalStorage won't effect the new policy? When I'm targeting sdk 30?

Comment: `I have implemented the new system file deletion dialog` What do you mean?

Comment: What is Basic file Explorer?

Comment: The dialog which is shown when you try to delete any media file in Android 11. Have you seen that?

Comment: `Keep the requestLegacyExternalStorage otherwise your app will not run on Android 10 devices. `

Comment: I have no idea which dialog you mean.

Comment: I think that for a cleaner app you can go for 'all files access' using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/hIBjua.jpg I'm talking about this dialog box when you attempt to delete the file in Android 11

Comment: I appreciate your help, @blackapps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238563/discussion-between-teekam-suthar-and-blackapps).

Comment: That picture tell me nothing. You should mention the code that gives that box.

Comment: @blackapps here's the code I followed to use system delete dialog - Check it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68079020/11141100

Comment: Enough would have been to say that you used requestDeletePermission() ;-) or better createDeleteRequest().